Upper bounds for minimum angle
What are the latest and best results on the asymptotic upper bound for the minimum angle between any pair of rays among $n$ rays in $\mathbb{R}^3$?
Any helpful answer would be appreciated. Thank you!

There is a large science devoted to this very question. Look for "spherical codes"

@FedorPetrov Thank you for your comment. However, do the tables on spherical codes contain asymptotic upper bound results? Thanks.

Certainly. Look for Kabatiansky - Levenshtein and beyond

@FedorPetrov Then what is the expression for the bound? Thank you.

Ah, I missed that the dimension 3 is fixed. Then you pack disjoint equal small caps on the sphere. The optimal density is the same as for packing disjoint disks on the plane (you know, locally the Earth is flat), i. e., hexagonal

@FedorPetrov How about the minimum angle between $n$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Thank you!

my previous comments were about this

@FedorPetrov By "Kabatiansky–Levenshtein," do you mean $A(n, \theta) \leq 2^{(0.5990 + o(1))n}$? If so, how do you obtain the estimated upper bound for the minimum angle? Thanks.

The bound must include $\theta$, right?

The connection is obvious: if you can not have more than $m$ rays with mutual angles at least $\theta$, than among every $m+1$ rays there is a pair with angles less than $\theta$, and viceversa

@FedorPetrov   Do you know the relationship between the maximal packing density $\Delta_{R^d}$ and the number of lines? Thanks.

Kabatiansky–Levenshtein is not only about optimal packing density, this is only a partial case of their bound for spherical codes

@FedorPetrov  May I ask if you have or know any estimational inequality between the maximal packing density $\Delta_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ and the number of lines, $n$? Thanks!
